# Interfaces: Importing files, processing them and exporting the results

Tags: dynamic, interface, button

We have a simple interface with two import file buttons, one field to enter a number $x$, one field to enter a file export name, and one 'Run' button. The mathematical operation when hitting 'Run' consists in multiplying both data sets, and dividing them by $x$ and plotting the result in a palette. Here's the code I have written:

```
TableForm[{
     Button["import A", (file = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]; 
     dataA = Import[file])], 
          Button["import B", (dataB = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]]; 
     CreatePalette[ListPlot[{dataA, dataB}]])], 
          InputField[Dynamic[x], Number, FieldHint -> "enter x"], 
          InputField[Dynamic[outputfilename], String, 
          FieldHint -> "enter output file name"], 
          Button["Run", result = (dataA dataB)/x; 
     Export[DirectoryName[file] <> outputfilename <> ".dat", result, "Table"];
     CreatePalette[ListPlot[result]]]}]
```

[image: interface appearance in notebook]

If I want the button RUN to be enabled only if 'import A' and 'import B' led to tables with identical dimensions, and additionally if the field 'x' and 'file name' contain valid data, how should I approach this ?

sample data:

```
A={{0.619, 0.384}, {0.62, 0.381}, {0.622, 0.381}, {0.623, 
  0.391}, {0.625, 0.383}, {0.627, 0.38}, {0.628, 0.374}, {0.63, 
  0.381}, {0.631, 0.383}, {0.633, 0.383}, {0.635, 0.376}, {0.636, 
  0.381}, {0.638, 0.382}, {0.64, 0.382}, {0.641, 0.384}, {0.643, 
  0.385}, {0.645, 0.383}}

B={{0.619, 0.343}, {0.62, 0.337}, {0.622, 0.341}, {0.623, 0.34}, {0.625,
   0.342}, {0.627, 0.335}, {0.628, 0.347}, {0.63, 0.36}, {0.631, 
  0.37}, {0.633, 0.37}, {0.635, 0.371}, {0.636, 0.367}, {0.638, 
  0.358}, {0.64, 0.362}, {0.641, 0.356}, {0.643, 0.368}, {0.645, 
  0.375}}
```

Comment: Please, specify what do you understand by valid data. Integers, reals, etc ?

Comment: Sorry, I will use always reals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this with data, perhaps you can post some example data. I've assumed the lists of data you import are all numbers. If you are unsure then you would need additional tests on the imported data before doing the calculation (see `MatrixQ`, `VectorQ` and their 2nd arguments).

Also I suspect that `PopupWindow` would be a better choice than `CreatePalette`.

Give this a go:

```
DynamicModule[{file, x, dataA, dataB, result, filename = $Canceled},

 Column[{
   Button["import A",
    file = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"];
    dataA = Import[file],
    Method -> "Queued"],

   Button["import B",
    file = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]];
    dataB = Import[file];
    If[ListQ[dataA] && ListQ[dataB],
     CreatePalette[ListPlot[{dataA, dataB}]]
     ],
    Method -> "Queued"],

   InputField[Dynamic[x], Number, FieldHint -> "enter x"],

   Button["Export File Name",
    filename = 
     SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "my file.dat", 
      WindowTitle -> "enter output file name"],
    Method -> "Queued"],

   Dynamic@
    If[Dimensions[dataA] == Dimensions[dataB] && NumberQ[x] && 
      filename =!= $Canceled && filename =!= $Failed,

     Button["Run",
      Export[filename, result = (dataA dataB)/x, "Table"];
      CreatePalette[ListPlot[result]],
      Method -> "Queued"],
     (* else *)
     Spacer[0]
     ]
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: Minor remark: I would use `FileExistsQ[filename]` instead of `filename =!= $Canceled && filename =!= $Failed`

Comment: Hi @RolfMertig. I don't think `FileExistsQ[filename]` will work prior to exporting the file.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I just copy-pasted it and except for the extra Import in  Button B, (`file = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]];`), which I removed, it works exactly how I need! Thanks!